# Deriving a general expression for the coefficient of $a_{n-2}$, given the roots of the equation are $(\alpha)_k$ for k = 1,2,3...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am self-studying Mathematical Methods for Physics using the book 'Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering : A Comprehensive Guide' by Riley.

For $ f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x +a_0  
         = a_n(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_n)$

they derived a general expression for the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ using summations.

How does one derive an expression for the $x^{n-2}$ from first principles and are there similar expressions that can be derived for the coefficients of $x^{n-k}$ for k = 3,4,5...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general recipe is :

1/ Expand the product into a sum

2/ Factor all the terms in $x^k$

3/ Identify the coefficients of the polynomials. (two polynoms are equal <=> their coeffs are equal)

This process enven has [its own Wikiepdia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)